# Lucene .Net Exception while parsing query with <EOF> at Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have a parsing a query to to find a word with lucene.net along with the file operation and in sequential operation the query parser was working fine and when I do the same operation with Parallel.Foreach Loop I am getting parser exception.
Below the code sample of both.

Working Code :

```
#region - Non Parallel Execution -

                using (var input = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
                {
                    using (var swFile = new StreamWriter(decryptingFilename))
                    {
                        while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            totalEncryptedContact++;
                            query = queryParser.Parse(line.Trim());
                            TopDocs resultDocs = searcher.Search(query, 1);
                            if (resultDocs.ScoreDocs.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                hits = resultDocs.ScoreDocs[0];
                                var documentFromSearcher = searcher.Doc(hits.Doc);
                                string msisdn = documentFromSearcher.Get("MSISDN");
                                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msisdn))
                                {
                                    swFile.WriteLine(msisdn);
                                    totalDecryptedContact++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                #endregion - Non Parallel Execution -
```

Exception Code with Parallel:

```
      using (var swFile = new StreamWriter(decryptingFilename))
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
            options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

            Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(file.FullName), options, newline =>
            {                       
                totalEncryptedContact++;
                query = queryParser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(newline.Trim()));                    
                TopDocs resultDocs = searcher.Search(query, 1);
                if (resultDocs.ScoreDocs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    hits = resultDocs.ScoreDocs[0];
                    var documentFromSearcher = searcher.Doc(hits.Doc);
                    string msisdn = documentFromSearcher.Get("MSISDN");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msisdn))
                    {
                        swFile.WriteLine(msisdn);
                        totalDecryptedContact++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Exception :
An exception of type 'Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException' occurred in Lucene.Net.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot parse '7465': Encountered "" at line 1, column 4.

Was expecting one of:

```
"(" ...

"*" ...

"^" ...

<QUOTED> ...

<TERM> ...

<FUZZY_SLOP> ...

<PREFIXTERM> ...

<WILDTERM> ...

"[" ...

"{" ...

<NUMBER> ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

":" ...

<TERM> ...

"*" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`QueryParser` is *not* thread-safe. You can construct a new on each iteration, though, they are pretty lightweight.

Also, I doubt that your use of `QueryParser.Escape` is going to do what you intend it to. That will escape all QueryParser syntax. So if you pass it, say `fieldToSearch:"my text"`, it will escape the quotes and colon and such, and after analysis, you may end up with a query that looks like: `defaultField:fieldtosearch defaultField:my defaultField:text`.